# If p is a prime, p divides $a^2+b^2$ and p divides $a^2$, then p divides $b^2$

Tags: number-theory

Can you help me prove this number theory claim:

If p is a prime, p divides $a^2+b^2$ and p divides $a^2$, then p divides $b^2$

Thanks

Comment: The squares are maybe there just to add some confusion.  Try ignoring them for a moment and see whether the question looks easier.

Comment: You don't even need $p$ to be prime. It's all red herrings.

Comment: @badjohn That's a good point, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Badjohn is right:  If $kp=a^2+b^2$ and $mp=a^2$ for some integers $k$ and $m$, then $(k-m)p=b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$p|a^2+b^2-a^2=b^2$

Especially $p|b$